# Como podría realizar la multiplicación de dos variables tipos BigInteger y BigDecimal en java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Tengo estas dos variables las cuales quiero multiplicar:

```
BigInteger total=detallePedido.getCantidad(); 
BigDecimal total2=detallePedido.getPrecio();
```

Luego el resultado quiere agregarselo a otra tipo BigDecimal:

```
detallePedido.setTotal();
```

Como podría lograr esto? Gracias.

Comment: A menos que trabajes en un país con una inflación tan alta como la de Venezuela o algún país de África con índices de hiperinflación, ¿Qué sentido tiene usar BigInteger y BigDecimal para pedidos y precios? Creo que estás abusando de los tipos de datos. Saludos

Comment: Que tal, tienes razón pero no esta mal saber como resolver este problema

Comment: Leyendo la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.math.BigInteger%29), `BigDecimal(BigInteger val)`, tan simple como eso. Una vez que ambas variables son tipo `BigDecimal` usas el método [`mutliply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply(java.math.BigDecimal)) y tendrás el resultado. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*BigDecimal* tiene un constructor que acepta un parametro tipo *BigInteger* convertiendo el parametro a un *BigDecimal*:

```
BigInteger total=detallePedido.getCantidad(); 
BigDecimal total2=detallePedido.getPrecio();
BigDecimal totalDec = new BigDecimal(total);
BigDecimal producto = total.multiply(total2);
```

Asi tienes tu resultado en tipo BigDecimal como quieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Stefan